# To assign an array to a function

Tags: functions, matrix

// Pre-defined parameter

```
kS = 2*(\[Pi]*NefS)/LambdaSS;
```

Here, NefS is a function of LambdaSS. The matrix m (i,j) defined corresponding value of NefS (jth component) with LambdaSS (ith component),

```
m = {{1.5, 2.83034}, {1.50476, 2.82655}, {1.50952, 2.82275}, {1.51429,
 2.81895}, {1.51905, 2.81516}, {1.52381, 2.81136},{1.52857, 2.80756},{1.53333, 2.80376}, {1.5381, 2.79996}, {1.54286, 2.79616}, {1.54762, 2.79236}, {1.55238, 2.78855}, {1.55714, 2.78475},{1.5619, 2.78094}, {1.56667, 2.77713}, {1.57143, 2.77333}, {1.57619, 2.76952}, {1.58095 , 2.76571}, {1.58571, 2.7619}, {1.59048 , 2.75809},{1.59524, 2.75428}, {1.6 , 2.75046}};
```

1. How do we define a function for a array?
2. Also, I need to plot LambdaSS with another parameter while taking only these values from the matrix. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: I find it hard to grasp the essence of your question. Please, post a _minimal_ example (e.g., all the constants seem to be very inessential to the problem at hand). Moreover, your problem needs a much better description. You probably want to make `NefS` a `Function` and maybe `Map` or `Apply` it to `m`. Maybe revisiting the documentation of such basic operations like `Part` would also help you.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for your suggestion. Have edited the question. Please have a look.